# HTML slideshow that can include new images

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, slideshow

I have a local folder with some images. I want to create a simple web page that displays all the images in the folder like a slideshow. However, I keep adding and removing pictures to that folder so the web page should be able to add the new pictures to or remove the deleted ones from the slideshow without refreshing the page.

I am far away from being a pro. I want to use the simplest design as possible. Maybe only a transition effect. Is CSS,HTML5 and Jquery enough for this kind of page?

Comment: If you want the images to change dynamically from a folder, you're going to have to do constant pulling on the client side to check if the source has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client side of things, so it is unable to check data on a storage. What you want to do is possible, but you need server sided script (eg PHP) to check for file changes.

The simplest way should be to write PHP code that checks your directory and returns the list of files you need, and you call this from Javascript via AJAX (to skip page reloading), in regular intervals (eg every 10 seconds should be enough). There is a handy function in JS to do repetitive calls: setInterval (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

One (of many) ways is to start with a XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org).

Feel free to ask if you have questions in detail.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what to do after getting the list of files with AJAX. How does one include that file list to the running slideshow?